# Updating Bootstrap Validation on partial view that are load on change of dropdown value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-mvc-partialview, bootstrapvalidator

I have a form, that contain a dropdown and this form is validated by `bootstrapValidation()`. when I change the value of dropdown, it loads a partial view with a list of text field. First time when I change ddl value, validation is working fine, but second time when I change the ddl value and it is not working.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("WareHouseProductionItemConsumptionSlave", "WareHouse", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "wareHouseConsumptionSlaveFormId", @class = "formValidator" }))
{
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Requisition Number</label>

             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.WareHouse_RequisitionFk, Model.RequisitionList as SelectList, "==Select Requisition No==", new { id = "ddlWareHouseRequisitionFk", @class = "searchingDropdown form-control ddlReset", required = "required", style = "width:100%" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WareHouse_RequisitionFk, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
         <div id="requisitionSlaveData"></div>
     </div>
}



@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$("#ddlShipmentInvoiceFk").change(function (e) {
            $("#ddlWareHouseRequisitionFk").change(function (e) {
                var requisitionId = $("#ddlWareHouseRequisitionFk").val();
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetWareHouseProductionItemRequisitionSlavePartial", "WareHouse")",
                    datatype: "Json",
                     data: { requisitionId: requisitionId },
                     success: function (data) {
                         $("#requisitionSlaveData").html(data);
                        $('.formValidator').bootstrapValidator();

                    }
                });                 
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: which validation not working ? In partial view or on main page ?

Comment: It's working now.